# Using Position to get position of string of a list of strings

Tags: string-manipulation

I can't seem to figure out how to use `Position` function correctly.  For example:

```
Position[{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "abc", "bbc", "cca"}, "cc"]
```

I would like the function to return `{3, 6}` as these are the only two positions in the list that contain the string "cc". I'm sure this probably has something to do with patterns, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way might be

```
 str = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "abc", "bbc", "cca"}
 Position[StringContainsQ[str, "cc"], True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

`Position` has some unusual defaults. As [`ref/Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) says

> The default level specification for Position is {0,Infinity}, with Heads->True.

So it is a little tricky to use `StringContainsQ` directly in a pattern given to `Position`, but it can be done.

```
Position[
  {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "abc", "bbc", "cca"},
  _?(StringContainsQ["cc"]), 
  {1}, 
  Heads -> False]
```

> `{{3}, {6}}`